# Upload image issue to server android php mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql

While I'm trying upload image to server (000webhost) through my android app by using php mysql I'M facing directry issue.

[Here is image of error
][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAK7S.jpg

Code where i am calling function in UpdateInfo.php to upload image.

```
else if(isset($_POST['image'])) { $result = $db->updateImage( $_POST['id'], $_POST['image'] );
```

DpOperation.php code where I'm performing all operation

```
<?php

 class DbOperation
 {
    private $con ;
    function __construct()
    {
        require_once dirname(__File__).'/DbConnect.php';
        $db = new DbConnect();
        $this->con = $db->connect();
        
    }
    // Create User
    function saveUser($phone_number ,$user_name ,$user_email , $image)
    {
        if($this->isEmailExist($user_email))
        {
            return "Email already Exist";
        }
        else
        {
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`phone_number`, `user_name`, `user_email` , image) VALUES (?,?,?,?);");
        $stmt->bind_param("ssss",$phone_number,$user_name,$user_email,$image);
        if($stmt->execute())
        {
            return "Account created Successfully";
        }
        else
        echo "problem";
    }
    }
    function userExixtance($phone_number)
    {
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE phone_number = ?");
        $stmt -> bind_param("s" , $phone_number);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        else
            return  0;
        
    }

    private function isEmailExist($user_email)
    {
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE user_email = ?") ;
        $stmt -> bind_param("s" , $user_email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        if ($stmt->num_rows > 0)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
            return 0;
    }

    function updateInfo($id ,$user_name )
    {
        
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("UPDATE users SET user_name = ? WHERE id = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("si", $user_name ,  $id);
        if($stmt->execute())
         return 1; 
         return 0;
    }
    function fetchUsers()
    {
        $stmt = "SELECT * FROM users";
        $raw = mysqli_query($this->con,$stmt);
        while ($res = mysqli_fetch_array($raw)) {
            $data[] = $res;
        }
        print(json_encode($data));
    }
    function updateImage( $id , $image )
    {
        $this->target_dir = "Images/";
        $image = $_POST['image'];
        $imageStore = rand()."_".time().".jpeg";
        $this->storage_dir = $this->target_dir."/".$imageStore;
        file_put_contents($this->target_dir, base64_decode($image));

        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("UPDATE users SET image = ? WHERE id = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("si", $image ,  $id);
        if($stmt->execute())
         return "uploaded";
         return "unable";
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `file_put_contents()` function expects a complete file name as an argument, you've provided only a directory for the file to go in. It looks like you have built the complete file name and stored it in a variable, but then forgot to use it. You probably want this:

```
file_put_contents($this->storage_dir, base64_decode($image));
```